# FCFS response time vs SJF response time (scheduling algorithms)

Tags: scheduling, job-scheduling

which of these algorithms is better in **response time**? (FCFS or SJF)

I want to know that does any of them dominant another one in response time?

I think SJF is always better in the side of response time. Can you **prove** it?

**Assumption**: both of these algorithms are non-preemptive.